# How to create view similar to AddressBook edit contact

Tags: iphone

Can anyone provide example of how to create contact view from address book.

Mostly I am interested in:

1. What UIKit class to use for Add Photo
2. What class to use for editing Name and Company
3. How to implement composite control where I am able to edit phone, ringtone

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've putted ImageView and a couple of TableViews with style set to Groped. I have one controller datasource for all my table views, that's why I set each table view tag property to unique int value to distinguish them in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Then everything is pretty standard, you are doing pushViewController and popViewControllerAnimated to show and hide details controller.

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you check out the [Address Book Programming guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html) section at the iPhone Developer site.

The iPhone SDK comes with pre-built classes and views that can handle selecting, editing or adding of all the address book data. You simply create one of these pre-built controllers (e.g. ABPersonViewController) and fill in the ID of the person, and which details the user can select/change.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's sample project QuickContacts covers [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html).